# Why does enum always return a strange response in a where clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, rails-activerecord

I have a model - `Activity`, that looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: activities
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  trackable_id   :integer
#  trackable_type :string(255)
#  owner_id       :integer
#  owner_type     :string(255)
#  key            :string(255)
#  parameters     :text
#  recipient_id   :integer
#  recipient_type :string(255)
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
#  read_status    :integer          default(0)
#

class Activity < PublicActivity::Activity
  enum read_status: [ :unread, :read ]

  attr_accessible :read_status
end
```

In my `ActivitiesController.rb` I added this:

```
  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def activity_params
      params.require(:activity).permit(:read_status)
    end
```

But when I do this in my console, I returns the same amount of records:

```
[13] pry(main)> Activity.where(read_status: "read").count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "activities"  WHERE "activities"."read_status" = 0
=> 12
[14] pry(main)> Activity.where(read_status: "unread").count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "activities"  WHERE "activities"."read_status" = 0
=> 12
```

Notice that both `where` calls are checking for `"read_status" = 0` even though that is clearly not the case.

In this case, the first should check for `read_status = 1`.

This is the second time I am having this problem with enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to access your activities status is by using

```
Activity.read
Activity.unread
```

You can check the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Comment: I was looking for that, but couldn't find it. Thanks! I knew there must be a simpler way! By the way, that documentation does not include class methods that return a collection like your example. I knew I looked through the docs and couldn't find an example. But your suggestion works perfectly.